# Правильно ли прописано условие

Tags: c++, c, математика

Есть математическая задача, которую я должен написать на плюсах, вроде что - то получилось, но у меня есть сомнения потому что результат не очень реалистичный, гляньте пожалуйста и скажите есть ли где в логике программы ошибки.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int epsilon_first(int k)
{
    int sn;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
    {
        sn = k * k * k;
        sum += sn;
    }
    return sum;

}
int epsilon_twice(int k, int l)
{
    int sn;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int l = 1; l <= 15; l++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)

            sn = k * k - 2 * k * l - k * k;
            sum += sn;
    }
    return sum;


}
int main() 
{
    int k = 1;
    int l = 1;
    int sum;
    sum = epsilon_first(k) * epsilon_twice(k, l);
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
    
}
```

Условие задачи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат выполнения программы: `-7260000`

Comment: Ну сами подумайте — все абсолютно члены положительны... а сумма отрицательна? :) Правильное значение — 983455. Кстати, Σ — это сигма, а не эпсилон...

Comment: `sn = k * k - 2 * k * l - k * k;` - это что за формула?

Comment: Да, уже увидел, накосячил с формулой

Comment: Это формула `(k - l)^2`, просто неправильно раскрыл скобки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так лучше:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int S2(int k) {
    int s = 0;

    for (int l = 1; l <= 15; ++l) s += (k - l) * (k - l);

    return s;
    }

int S1() {
    int s = 0;

    for (int k = 1; k <= 10; ++k) s += k * k * k * S2(k);

    return s;
    }

int main() {
    cout << S1();
    }
```

Вывод совпадает с указанным @Harry.

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII Обратите внимание на главное принципиальное отличие от ваших попыток — в первую сумму вторая входит как *зависимая* от `k` функция, в то время как вы пытались их множить (еще и неверно). (Сразу не обратил внимания, поэтому говорю об этом тут, в комментарии к ответу.)

Comment: Понял, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, неверно. Достаточно пары циклов:

```
int summ, result = 0;
for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++) 
{
    sum = 0;
    for (int l = 1; l <= 15; l++)
        sum += k * k - 2 * k * l + l * l;
    result += k * k * k * sum;
}
```

Comment: `+ k * k;` - ? *(нужно ещё 1 символ...)*

Comment: @Igor Угу, знак неверный заметил, а это нет :=)